# clientIf field in Android BluetoothGatt class

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android `BluetoothGatt.class` has `mClientIf` private field. Most of the log messages related to BLE events contain this value. For example:

> onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=17

What does the `mClientIf` field represent? What does the *integer* value of this field tell?

Answer (score 1):

`mClientf` is a `scannerId` from Bluetooth scanner,

If you dig through the source of BluetoothGatt and BluetoothLeScanner you can find the following:

`mBluetoothGatt.unregisterClient(scannerId);` method is implemented in

*GattService.java* `unregisterClient(int clientIf)`

---

**BluetoothLeScanner.java**

```
...
/**
 * Application interface registered - app is ready to go
 */
@Override
public void onScannerRegistered(int status, int scannerId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onScannerRegistered() - status=" + status +
            " scannerId=" + scannerId + " mScannerId=" + mScannerId);
    synchronized (this) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            try {
                if (mScannerId == -1) {
                    // Registration succeeds after timeout, unregister client.
                    mBluetoothGatt.unregisterClient(scannerId);
                } else {
                    mScannerId = scannerId;
                    mBluetoothGatt.startScan(mScannerId, mSettings, mFilters,
                            mResultStorages,
                            ActivityThread.currentOpPackageName());
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "fail to start le scan: " + e);
                mScannerId = -1;
            }
        } else {
            // registration failed
            mScannerId = -1;
        }
        notifyAll();
    }
}
...
```

---

**GattService.java**

```
...
/**
 * Unregister the current application and callbacks.
 */
private IBluetoothGatt mService;
.
.   
public void unregisterClient(int clientIf) {
    GattService service = getService();
    if (service == null) return;
    service.unregisterClient(clientIf);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say with absolute certainty, but looking at how it's used in the rest of the class, I would say it's a unique ID assigned by the layer underneath called `IBluetoothGatt`.